# Node.js date parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, express

I am creating a node.js endpoint that accepts a start date/time and end date/time as parameters. I had been passing them as a string ie:

```
var body = {
            relatedObjectId: "561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8",
            startTime : "11/13/2015 03:00:00PM",
            endTime: "11/13/2015 03:30:00PM"
        };
```

and in my service class:

```
var timeTicket = new TimeTicket();
timeTicket.tutorId = tutorId;
timeTicket.startTime = new Date(startTime);
timeTicket.endTime = new Date(endTime);

timeTicket.save(function(err, timeTicket){
    if(err){
        return next(err, null);
    }

    return next(null, timeTicket);
});
```

However, the cast always fails so i end up with a date in 1970 for startTime and endTime values. It would seem the obvious solution would be to use a UTC format, but what's the right way to do that?

Comment: Use an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, eg `"2015-11-13T15:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: Generally, parsing of strings with the Date constructor is unreliable and should not be used. However, Node.js environments might be sufficiently standardised for ISO 8601 UTC formatted strings to be reliable.

Comment: @RobG, are you suggesting using the number based format is superior? Under what conditions would it be unreliable to parse a string?

Comment: @EricH—if by "number based" you mean passing a time value (e.g. seconds or milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) then yes. Parsing of strings using the Date constructor (which is the same as using Date.parse) has always been problematic in ECMAScript. However, Node.js doesn't carry as much baggage as browsers and code is generally written for one environment rather than the unknown plethora of javascript implementations, so it may be OK to use ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use ISO 8601 format as Phil suggested, or simply pass the date as milliseconds (since 1970).

For example, `new Date(1447378736842)` is the same as `new Date("2015-11-13T01:38:56.842Z")`.

To get the current date in ISO 8601 format, you might do something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```

**tl;dr** version: This is what your `body` object should look like. I used milliseconds for `startTime` and an ISO 8601 string for `endTime` for demonstration purposes. Both are valid.

```
var body = {
            relatedObjectId: "561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8",
            startTime : 1447378736842,
            endTime: "2015-11-13T01:38:56.842Z"
        };
```